# How to add disable the other dropdowns when a value is selected in one dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

So I have multiple dropdowns on my page and i want to create a method, that if a value is selected in one dropdown, the other dropdown disables, which is no value can be selected in the other dropdown and it becomes grey and vice versa.
MY HTML is :

```
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="1">
      <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(list1)">Select Months</span>
      <ul id="list1_items" class="items" name="month">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Apr-2021">April </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="May-2021">May </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jun-2021">June </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jul-2021">July</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Aug-2021">August</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Sep-2021">September</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Oct-2021">October</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Nov-2021">November</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Dec-2021">December</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jan-2021">January </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Feb-2021">February</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Mar-2021">March </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
      <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(list2)">Select Quarter</span>
      <ul id="list2_items" class="items" name="quarter">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter1">Quarter 1- Apr - Jun</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter2">Quarter 2- Jul - Sep</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter3">Quarter 3- Oct - Dec</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter4">Quarter 4- Jan - Mar </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

If someone could please help me.
Thankyou.

Comment: Share code please

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary** to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The behaviour I require is disabling list2 if a value is selected in list1 and vice versa

Comment: getElements(&#39;list2&#39;) what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` and then set `disabled` property to true

```
let list1 = new Set();
let list2 = new Set();

document.querySelector('#list1_items').addEventListener('change', e => {
 e.target.checked ? list1.add(e.target.value) : list1.delete(e.target.value); 
  if(list1.size) 
      document.querySelectorAll('#list2_items > li > input').forEach(el => el.disabled = true); 
  else 
      document.querySelectorAll('#list2_items > li > input').forEach(el => el.disabled = false);
});

document.querySelector('#list2_items').addEventListener('change', e => {
 e.target.checked ? list2.add(e.target.value) : list2.delete(e.target.value); 
  if(list2.size) 
     document.querySelectorAll('#list1_items > li > input').forEach(el => el.disabled = true);
  else
    document.querySelectorAll('#list1_items > li > input').forEach(el => el.disabled = false);
});
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/debraj1983/pen/WNpVdZp)

Comment: If you select a checkbox from `#list2` first this will not work

Comment: @caramba Yes, I just followed as posted in the question.

Comment: But in this if I select in the list2 list1 doesnot get disabled and even if i clear list 1 values list 2 remains disabled

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery this is pretty straightforward.  Code attached.  If not, comment back, but the approach is the same.

- Give all your selects the same class name.

```html
<select class="selectClass">
        <option value="test1">test1</option>
        <option value="test11">test11</option>
        <option value="test111">test111</option>
    </select>
    <select class="selectClass">
        <option value="test2">test2</option>
        <option value="test22">test22</option>
        <option value="test222">test222</option>
    </select>
    <select class="selectClass">
        <option value="test3">test3</option>
        <option value="test33">test33</option>
        <option value="test333">test333</option>
    </select>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".selectClass").on('change', function () {
                $(".selectClass").not($(this)).prop("disabled", "disabled")
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```js
const genderDD = document.getElementById('gender-dd');
const countryDD = document.getElementById('country-dd');

genderDD.onchange = function(ev) {
  const gender = ev.target.value;
  countryDD.disabled = gender ? true : false;
}

countryDD.onchange = function(ev) {
  const conuntry = ev.target.value;
  genderDD.disabled = conuntry ? true : false;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="country-dd">
  <option value="">Please Select Country</option>
  <option value="india">India</option>
  <option value="pak">Pak</option>
  <option value="srilanka">Srilanka</option>
</select>

<select name="" id="gender-dd">
  <option value="">Please Select Gender</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the CSS `pointer-events: none;` after you figured out which `<div>` is the other one. Something like this:

```js
var listIds = ['list1', 'list2'];
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.items input[type="checkbox"]');
checkboxes.forEach( checkbox => {
    // every checkbox needs one event listener on change
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
        // if the checkbox is clicked run the following code...
        // remove this checkbox div id from the list of IDs
        listIds = listIds.filter(e => e !== checkbox.closest('div').id);
        listIds.forEach( id => {
            // add the class "disable" to the remainig div
            document.querySelector(`#${id}`).classList.add('disable')
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.disable {
  border: solid 2px red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="1">
      <!--<span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(&#39;list1&#39;)">Select Months</span>-->
      <ul id="list1_items" class="items" name="month">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Apr-2021">April </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="May-2021">May </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jun-2021">June </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jul-2021">July</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Aug-2021">August</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Sep-2021">September</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Oct-2021">October</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Nov-2021">November</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Dec-2021">December</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jan-2021">January </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Feb-2021">February</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Mar-2021">March </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
      <!--<span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(&#39;list2&#39;)">Select Quarter</span>-->
      <ul id="list2_items" class="items" name="quarter">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter1">Quarter 1- Apr - Jun</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter2">Quarter 2- Jul - Sep</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter3">Quarter 3- Oct - Dec</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter4">Quarter 4- Jan - Mar </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <select id="cat_user">
    <option>select option</option>
    <option value="Super Admin">Super Admin</option>
    <option value="Event Admin">Event Admin</option>
</select>

<select id="event_name">
    <option value="ICT4U">ICT4U</option>
    <option value="Fun Run">Fun Run</option>
</select>`$('#cat_user').change(function () {


    if ($('#cat_user option:selected').text() == "Event Admin") {
        $('#event_name').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $('#event_name').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});`
```